# Insert a contact into a journey in the middle in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to insert a contact into a journey in the middle and not from the beginning?
If I have to stop the journey and continue it later from a certain point and not from the beginning, is there such a way?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your ask is to change journey activities in an active journey, so they will have effect for contacts already in the journey. Unfortunately it is only possible to insert a contact from the beginning of the journey, as the only way into a journey is an Entry Source.

You will always be able to create and activate a new version of a journey, where new contacts will be entered into. Contacts who are already in the old version, will finish moving throughout the journey, but no new contacts will be admitted.

I always advise to have as short journeys as possible, and no journey should have a duration of more than 2 weeks. I have seen implementations with journeys which consist of multiple long wait steps, and have a total duration of multiple months. This is really not advisable, as you will not be able to update any upcoming steps for contacts currently in a journey. Instead one should split a single journey in multiple shorter ones, and inject contacts in the subsequent ones using e.g. Automation Studio.